# Integrate Caffe model into ROS

Tags: integration, ros, caffe

I'm looking at integrating a trained Caffe network into ROS and was wondering if anyone had any experience with this?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://tzutalin.blogspot.tw/2015/06/integrate-ros-into-caffe.html
Integrate Caffe into ROS indigo.